# Multiple IF AND statements with another formula(computation) as answers

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a formula for the following scenario:

`If E16=200 AND P17=0`  output would be the answer for `P16*S4`

`If E16=200 AND P17>0`  output would be the answer for `P16*N4`

`If E16=1   AND P17=0`  output would be the answer for `P16*S2`

`If E16=1   AND P17>0`  output would be the answer for `P16*H2`

`If E16=3`              output would be the `sum(Q16:U16)`

It worked when I put the first two conditions for `E16=200` but when I added the rest, it gave me an error. Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52881250/edit), adding the formulas in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an `IF` formula that will evaluate for all scenarios, try this:

`=IF(E16=200,IF(P17<=0,P16*S4,P16*N4),IF(E16=1,IF(P17<=0,P16*S2,P16*H2),IF(E16=3,SUM(Q16:U16),"No Value")))`

It first evaluates for `E16` being equal to **200**. If `E16` *is* equal to **200**, it moves on to evaluate `P17`. If `E16` *is not* equal to **200**, the formula then checks if `E16` is equal to **1**.

If `E16` *is* equal to **1**, it moves on to evaluate `P17`. If `E16` *is not* equal to **1**, the formula then checks if `E16` is equal to **3**.

If `E16` *is* equal to **3**, the formula then sums the range `Q16:U16`. If `E16` *is not* equal to **3**, the formula returns the words, "**No Value**".

There is no error-handling in this formula, so if you need that, you can wrap this in an `IFERROR` function.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you for explaining it too. I ended up doing it differently but it worked as well:  =IF(AND(E16=200,P17=0),(P16*S4),IF(E16=200,P16*N4,IF(AND(E16=1,P17=0),(P16*S2),IF(E16=1,P=16*H2,IF(E16=3,SUM(Q16:U16),"NA")))))

Comment: I'm glad I could help, @KC! If my answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted (which will benefit both of us as well as the community as a whole). The way I set up the formula, the logic check is cleaner and less redundant. By testing scenarios as few times as needed, it improves the efficiency of the formula as well as makes it easier to understand. You can always gauge the cleanliness of a formula by breaking it out line by line (typically at the `,`, but wherever it makes the most logical sense). That way you can see excessive parentheses, repetitive pieces, etc.

Comment: Your formula worked as well!  Looks cleaner too :)  Thanks!